# How to adjust border around StaticText object programatically?

Tags: wxpython

How do I adjust the border of a StaticText object programatically given the StaticText object?  It seems there is a SizerItem associated with this object, but I cannot figure out how to find it.

I see the StaticText object has a GetBorder() function, but this function returns wx.NO_BORDER, so it's not what I'm looking for.

Minimal working example:

```
import wx
import wx.xrc


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(
            self,
            parent,
            id=wx.ID_ANY,
            title=wx.EmptyString,
            pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
            size=wx.Size(500, 300),
            style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL,
        )

        self.SetSizeHints(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)

        box_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        labeled_box_sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(
            wx.StaticBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, u"label"), wx.VERTICAL
        )

        self.m_text_top = wx.StaticText(
            labeled_box_sizer.GetStaticBox(),
            wx.ID_ANY,
            u"Border = 0",
            wx.DefaultPosition,
            wx.DefaultSize,
            0,
        )
        self.m_text_top.Wrap(-1)

        labeled_box_sizer.Add(self.m_text_top, 0, wx.ALL, 0)

        self.m_text_bottom = wx.StaticText(
            labeled_box_sizer.GetStaticBox(),
            wx.ID_ANY,
            u"Border = 5",
            wx.DefaultPosition,
            wx.DefaultSize,
            0,
        )
        self.m_text_bottom.Wrap(-1)

        labeled_box_sizer.Add(self.m_text_bottom, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        box_sizer.Add(labeled_box_sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(box_sizer)
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

    def __del__(self):
        pass


app = wx.App()
window = MyFrame(None)
window.Show()

text = window.m_text_top

# text.SetBorder(5)  # <-- no such method exists

app.MainLoop()
```

I've tried `GetSizer()` and `GetContainingSizer()` functions with no such luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do get the `wx.SizerItem` like this:

```
item = text.GetContainingSizer().GetItem(text)
```

If you want to just keep a reference to the sizer item instead of fetching it each time, it is returned from the sizer's `Add` method when you add the static text.

Once you have the item then you can adjust the sizer-specific attributes for that item. Be sure to call the sizer's or containing widget's `Layout` method when you are done adjusting.